# Применяются изменения транзакции в случае ошибки

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, transaction

Ошибка заключается в следующем: выполняю тестовую транзакцию, внутри которой есть ошибка.
По моим соображениям, код внутри не должен отрабатывать, но почему-то это происходит.

```
START TRANSACTION;
update buildingmaterials set Price = Price - ((Price * 25) / 100) where Code = 7;
DROP TABLE abasda;
COMMIT;
```

DROP TABLE abasda; - эта строка кода выдаст ошибку за неимением такой таблицы в выбранной БД. Вопрос следующий: почему выполняется первая строка в транзакции?

Comment: Откройте Reference Manual и изучите список запросов, вызывающих немедленную фиксацию транзакции (immediate commit).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html